# Resolving a callable into a variable without calling it

Tags: php, oop, callable

I have a class which has a `$action` variable, which takes a callable as it's value. Normally, when initializing this value, I could do something like this:

```
$this->action = function() {
   echo "My function";
}
```

I would then call the function by doing something like this:

```
$this->action();
```

The class itself looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Resolves an non-callable action
 */
class ActionResolver
{
    private $action;

    /**
     * Action constructor.
     *
     * @param string $action
     */
    public function __construct($action)
    {
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    public function resolve()
    {
        $actionResolver = new ActionResolver();
        $results = ...
        $this->action = $actionResolver->resolveCallable($results);
    }

    /**
     * @return callable
     */
    public function getAction()
    {
        return $this->action;
    }
}
```

In the `resolveCallable()` function, the action should be resolved by another object's method by the results of the `$results` variable. This method is in the `ActionResolver` class. The method looks like this:

```
public function resolveCallable(array $results)
{
    $class = $results[0];
    $method = null;
    if (isset($results[1])) {
        $method = ...
    }

    $object = new $class;
    if (!is_null($method)) {
        return $class->$method();
    }
    return function() {};
}
```

The method and class get's resolved by a string taken from the `$results` variable. The class and method name are both valid and work.

When I try to call this, it returns the return value from the method, but not the method itself.

How can I return the method itself instead of the contents of the method without calling it?

Comment: Quite honestly, this is a bit convoluted. Can you boil it down to a simpler example?

Comment: I can't really simplify it. It's litterly returning an callable from a class method.

Comment: What I'm most unclear about is how exactly your three big code snippets go together.

Comment: The first and second are just one class, the $action variable is in that one class. The `ActionResolver` gets instantiated with a string which looks someting like `MyClass::myMethod`. The last code snippet is the `resolveCallable` function in the `ActionResolver`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return value.

Instead

```
    return $class->$method();
```

use

```
    return $class->$method;
```